# Capacitor effects

Tags: electricity

I've read about capacitor and its operations, and I'm still confused about this question: 
lets assume I have circuit which I have source voltage parallel to capacitor and I've waited amount of time till the capacitor is fully charged, so in other words the voltage of the source is equal to the Vc (voltage on the capacitor) ; 
afterwards I have appended to the circuit a resistor which it's parallel to the capacitor i.e I have now source voltage parallel with charged capacitor and both are paralleled with resistor , my question will the capacitor now flow current to the resistor? if so, how could the capacitor discharge/flow current to the resistor if there's the source voltage on it(it's stable) which supposedly can't flow current to capacitor or from it...

my question how could also capacitor after being charged will be discharged although there's a stable voltage source connected to it?!

thanks for helpers

Comment: Rule #1 All voltage sources are stable until loaded due to effective series resistance = Vol / Iol or (Vcc-Voh)/Ioh This ratio of Vol/Vcc is called % load regulation.   SIMulation= http://tinyurl.com/y8c3w5t8  R=0 is only an assumption

Comment: ...except **ideal** voltage sources which have no series resistance. This is the kind you usually encounter in a circuit analysis course.

Answer (score 1):

In ideal circuit the voltage on the capacitor is not going to change as it is connected in parallel to an ideal voltage source. The relation between voltage and current in ideal capacitor is given by:
$$i=C\frac{dv}{dt}$$

But we said the voltage is not changing, therefore the derivative above is zero. So the current sourced/sinked by the capacitor is zero as well.

Comment: but if so, then you assume that whole inverter Cmos is wrong? I'm saying that because in inverter Cmos at vout you have capacitor, it gets discharged although the voltage on it is stable "vcc" !

Comment: If you have some specific circuit in mind and a question about it - post it as a separate question. The answer is for the question as it stands right now.

Comment: I started understand .. so lets assume that I have appended another resistor(another from the one that I already appended in parallel with capacitor) between source voltage and capacitor( now they are not in parallel..there's resistor between them) .. now can capacitor flow/discharge current to the parallel resistor?! thanks

Comment: @Ryan, in a DC circuit in steady state there is never current through capacitors. Just because the formula above - steady state means no changes. No changes mean derivatives are zero. If you are not talking about steady state - better draw a circuit where you place switches which connect/disconnect whatever is triggering the non-steady state. It is hard to follow the verbal description.

Answer (score 0):

No, there will be no current flow from your capacitor to the resistor.  I=C*dv/dt, so without any change in voltage across the capacitor no current can flow.  The voltage source ensures that there is no change in the voltage.

Similarly the capacitor will never discharge as long as there's a voltage source across it.

This assumes that the voltage source is ideal.  Any source impedance could lead to a current flow when a load is attached across the capacitor.

Comment: I started understand .. so lets assume that I have appended another resistor(another from the one that I already appended in parallel with capacitor) between source voltage and capacitor( now they are not in parallel..there's resistor between them) .. now can capacitor flow/discharge current to the parallel resistor?! thanks

Comment: @Ryan in the transient condition (right after you connect the parallel resistor) current will flow from the capacitor.  After a long time though the circuit will reach steady-state, and if nothing changes there will be no current flow from the capacitor.

Comment: Alright, but it's still in the same problem ; if I have capacitor with voltage that's not the source voltage (I mean the voltage at capacitor isn't the voltage of the source) so the capacitor will discharge or charge?!

Comment: See Eugene Sh's comment above.

Comment: I'm not understanding why the voltage on the capacitor is related to time, I mean why Vc is VC(t) ?!

Comment: @Ryan In that case go here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor Study that article from top to bottom, then come back and ask specific questions about anything you don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

No, the capacitor will not supply current to the resistor. As long as the capacitor is parallel to the voltage source the voltage across the capacitor will remain constant. As long as the capacitor voltage remains constant there will be no current flow into or out of it. So, the resistor current must come from the voltage source and the capacitor voltage will remain constant.

Comment: I started understand .. so lets assume that I have appended another resistor(another from the one that I already appended in parallel with capacitor) between source voltage and capacitor( now they are not in parallel..there's resistor between them) .. now can capacitor flow/discharge current to the parallel resistor?! thanks

Comment: guys I'm not talking in the steady state, does that matter to aware you? if so.. then I don't no if there's difference between state or general state..

Comment: You can't keep changing the question mid stream. It makes it too confusing to follow the different answers and comments. Ask a new question if you need to.

Comment: I'm not understanding why the voltage on the capacitor is related to time, I mean why Vc is VC(t) ?!

Comment: We live in a universe with (at least) four dimensions...everything in it is a function of time. I never said anything about Vc(t) so why are you asking me this? I said that the voltage is **constant**. In other words, \$V_C(t)=V_C(0)\$.